# Missing `From form` option in the section `Select event source`

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a script for a form. I wanted to create a trigger for `onFormSubmit()` function, however, I am missing the option `From form` in the section `Select event source` (the picture attached below). Is there anything I am missing?

For now I am trying the script from this site: https://codewithcurt.com/google-form-using-apps-script-to-populate-google-sheet/

[image: Lack of "From form" option]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your script is a standalone script.

Please newly create a script and then create the trigger from the script editor of the form.

Reference:

[Creating a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script)